# What sets an "interface name" apart from a "class name"?

Tags: java, language-lawyer, jvm-bytecode

In [paragraph 4.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.2) of the java 8 specification (similarly in a few other places around there) it is mentioned

> class_index
>
> The value of the class_index item must be a valid index into the constant_pool table. The constant_pool entry at that index must be a CONSTANT_Class_info structure (§4.4.1) representing a class or interface type that has the field or method as a member.
>
> **The class_index item of a CONSTANT_Methodref_info structure must be a class type, not an interface type.**

I've looked around but as far as I can tell, it is impossible from the bytecode alone to tell apart interface types from class types i.e. to actually check this requirement before resolving the named class/interface at runtime against a class loader.

Am I correct in that assumption or did I miss a way to check this requirement from for a single CONSTANT_Class_info in a class file in isolation?

Comment: I think this is correct. The class file of class `com.pany.A` contains only the name of class / interface `com.pany.B`. Without reading the class file of class / interface `com.pany.B` you cannot decide whether `com.pany.B` is a class or an interface. But without reading the class file of `com.pany.B` you also cannot verify that the mentioned method exists / is valid

Comment: What is the problem of reading the `tag` field? It has the value of CONSTANT_Fieldref, CONSTANT_Methodref or CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref, depending of the specific info object. Is it that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Progman that is what I am planning to do now: internally tag the Class_info with "interface" or "class" if it is referenced by a Methodref/InterfaceMethodref/etc... Because of the phrasing I was confused and thought that info was duplicated and available explicitly somewhere else, that's mainly why I asked.

Comment: I guess the compiler would know at construction time. If things change and the entry points to a name which is now an interface the VM would fail with an Error at validation or runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right, the `CONSTANT_Class_info` won’t tell you whether the referenced type is an interface and besides actually resolving the type, you can only collect hints within your current class file about the expected nature of the type and perhaps detect, when it has been used inconsistently.

Besides `CONSTANT_Methodref_info` expecting a declared type not to be an interface and `CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref_info` expecting it to be an interface, the presence of a type reference in the [super_class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-G) field implies a non-interface type whereas any type present in the [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-H) array implies an interface.

In case of nested types, you may check the [InnerClasses Attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.6), which lists all nested types with their access flags, including `ACC_INTERFACE`.

Further, each type used as an annotation is technically an interface, though the annotation attributes do not use `CONSTANT_Class_info` pool items but rather refer to type names and signature strings (`CONSTANT_Utf8_info`) directly.

Comment: Your collection of additional hints to consider is appreciated :)